# Optimal scheduling policy for two server model

Tags: queueing-theory

Suppose there are two servers with exponential arrival rates $\mu_{1}$ and $\mu_2$ such that $\mu_1 > \mu_2$. These two servers have a shared infinite buffer, where there is independent Poisson arrival with rate $\lambda$. What is an optimal scheduling policy in these two sense :

1. Throughput optimal that is it achieves the maximum capacity region.
2. It reduces the mean time spent by a customers in the system.

I have a feeling that the greedy policy should be optimal, that is choose the faster server if it is free, otherwise choose the other one. Never keep the servers idle. I have no idea as to how one would prove optimality.

In the case of throughput optimality perhaps the greedy policy can stabilize an arrival rate of $\mu_1 + \mu_2$. Then it would be throughput optimal.

Comment: Suppose one server is so much faster that it can complete three jobs before the other finishes one.  Wouldn't it make sense for small $\lambda$ to leave a single job in the queue even if the slow one is idle?

Comment: yes you are right. I was thinking about that. But my question is whether we can derive an optimal policy, which will be dependent on the values of $\mu_1, \mu_2$ and $\lambda$.

Comment: The answer is "yes," and this problem has been well-studied in the literature. Cf. http://www.kellogg.northwestern.edu/research/math/papers/592.pdf for the optimal policies where stalling of either server is allowed.